# Get data from multiple URLs using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, url

I'm trying to do the following-

1. Go to a web page, enter a search term.
2. Get some data from it.
3. It in turn has multiple URLs in it. I need to parse each one of them to get some data out of them.

I can do 1 and 2. I do not understand how I can go to all the URLs and get data (which is similar in all the URLs, but not the same) from them.

EDIT: More information-
I input the search terms from a csv file, get a few IDs (with URLs) from each page. I'd like to go to all these URLs to get more IDs from the following page. I want to write all these into a CSV file. 
Basically, I want my output to be something like this

```
Level1 ID1   Level2 ID1   Level3 ID
             Level2 ID2   Level3 ID
             .
             .
             .
             Level2 IDN   Level3 ID
Level1 ID2   Level2 ID1   Level3 ID
             Level2 ID2   Level3 ID
             .
             .
             .
             Level2 IDN   Level3 ID
```

There can be multiple Level2 IDs for each Level1 ID. But there will be only one corresponding Level3 ID for each Level2 ID.

CODE that I've written so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen

colnames = ['A','B','C','D']
data = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=colnames)
listofdata= list(data.A)
id = '\n'.join(listofdata[1:]) #to skip header


def download_gsm_number(gse_id):
    url = "http://www.example.com" + id
    readurl = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(readurl)
    soup1 = str(soup)
    gsm_data = readurl.read()
    #url_file_handle.close()
    pattern=re.compile(r'''some(.*?)pattern''')  
    data = pattern.findall(soup1)
    col_width = max(len(word) for row in data for word in row)
    for row in data:
        lines = "".join(row.ljust(col_width))
        sequence = ''.join([c for c in lines])
        print sequence
```

But this is taking all the ids at once into the URL. As I mentioned before, I need to get level2 ids from the level1 ids given as input. Further, from level2 ids, I need level3 ids. Basically, if I get just one part (getting either level2 or level3 ids) from it, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Explore Scrapy. If you think it is an overkill, explore BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 2):

I believe your answer is [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html).

It is actually as easy as going:

```
web_page = urllib.urlopen(url_string)
```

And then with that you can do normal file operations such as:

```
read()
readline()
readlines()
fileno()
close()
info()
getcode()
geturl()
```

From there I would suggest using BeautifulSoup to parse which is as easy as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.read())
```

And then you can do all the wonderful [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) operations on it.

I would imagine Scrapy is overkill and there is a lot more overhead involved. BeautifulSoup has some great documentation, examples, and is just plain easy to use.